# Using Google direction api in iOS 6

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, ios6-maps

Can I use Google map direction APIs to draw poly line on apple maps (obviously on the mapView) in iOS6?

If yes then will it be approved by apple?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how could you use google maps api to draw polylines on apple maps?? Do you mean mapView??

Answer (score 0):

Then ofcourse they will approve. Now there is an issue arised with ios6 apple maps. So they won't force any developers to use only apple maps.

And also if you want to give support to older versions of ios devices then you need to integrate the google directions api only. So no need to worry about the approval about the google directions api.

Comment: I really feel bad to see the images about the issues in apple maps here. http://mashable.com/2012/09/20/google-maps-ios-6-apple-approval-report/#89953London-UK